# custom data in formatter for highchart point

Tags: highcharts

I have a bar chart where I want to add an url to the xAxis legend

the data looks like :

```
{
              name: 'Title,
              y: 123,
              thumbnailURL: 'blabla.com',
}

xAxis: {
      gridLineWidth: 1,
      type: 'category',
      labels: {
        x: -130,
        useHTML: true,
        align: 'left',
        formatter() {//get the url here}
```

The formater function must use this 3 values to draw what i want

DEMO :
https://jsfiddle.net/6a97ckzr/2/

But I can't find a way for the `this` inside the formatter function to have the custom property url (different for each data value.

I tried all, but none work

```
chart = {
  series: [
    {
      keys: ['thumbnailURL', 'y'],
      data: [{
          name: v.name,
          y: v.value,
          thumbnailURL: v.thumbnailURL,
        }]
      }),
    },
  ],
}

chart = {
  series: [
    {
      keys: ['thumbnailURL', 'y'],
      data: [[
           v.name,
          v.value,
          v.thumbnailURL,
        ]]
      }),
    },
  ],
}
```

How do I get my custom value in the labels ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case `this.value` is a data point name. If you want to get some other property from a point you can use:

```
this.chart.series[0].options.data[this.pos].customUrl
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/h24sc1gn/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.formatter

Comment: I see, thanks for the answer.
Is this is the only way? it looks a bit ugly to me

Comment: Hi @Bobby, Alternatively, you can store some information in the name and get it in the formatter function. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/h24sc1gn/1/

Comment: Ok, Thank you :)

Comment: How to achieve this on Android HighCharts ?